# How to create a searcher which looks for more than one value in a database?

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter, match, google-query-language

it's nice to be here and join this forum.

I have an issue which I would like to solve.

I have a database, where I would like to input multiple locations, and then, to have displayed the IDs and region of multiple clients next to it.

Say, for example, that I have a sheet with the info of clients.

| Searcher |  | ClientID | City | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Caracas |  | 01 | Berlin | Europe |
| Berlin |  | 02 | Monaco | Europe |
|  |  | 03 | Caracas | LatAm |

I would like to copy and paste the names of my cities in the cells under the Searcher column and that only the cities displayed there are shown under the results.

In the above example, I would like my sheet to show both the info of Client #1 and Client #3.

The closest which I have made it to the solution of this problem can be seen in this spreadsheet.

[Database Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GhrtlzSQMxirOUkrqZX0Q_OrpYuQY9oO63c5x8-ZknM/edit?usp=sharing)

But sadly, it only works with one value. In the sheet I shared, I would like to have the info show the same fiels for both "Upper Marlboro" and "Darlington".

The sheet above can be edited to test this.

Resume:
**Is there a way to solve this issue a create a multiple value searching machine in Google Sheets?**

---

I have tried before with the `FILTER` and `SEARCH` formulas, like this:
`=FILTER($P$3:$Z,SEARCH(B4,$Y$3:$Y))`

And with Sheet Queries, like this:
`=QUERY(CityDB,"SELECT * WHERE J = 'Fairfax'")`

But sadly, it only has allowed me to search for just one value.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=FILTER(H3:J, REGEXMATCH(I3:I, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B4:B)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=QUERY(H3:J, "where I matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B4:B)&"'", )
```

Comment: That was great and extremely quick!
Thank you so much.